# display:inline-block not always working

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, displaytag

I have the following code in a user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="myControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="myControl" %>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .RowBGImage
    {
    background-image:url('tableBG.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    display:block;
    }
    td 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
    .HeaderPadding 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
</style>
```

123456
                    78%
                
                
                    Type
                
                
                    3 Days
                
                
                    1d 11h 30m

The code behind testing code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Control myControl = LoadControl("myControl.ascx");
            myControl.ID = "test" + i;
            Controls.Add(myControl);
        }
    }
```

In my code behind I add multiple entries of the user control above and I want the "boxes" (each div) to be horizontally aligned like so:

[image]

That works fine if I test the page locally on my dev machine, but when I upload it to the IIS server it gets messed up and lists them vertically instead, like this:

[image]

How can I fix that behaviour?

HTML code from source view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style>
    .RowBGImage
    {
    background-image:url('tableBG.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    }
    td 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
    .HeaderPadding 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#003366">
    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTg2Njc2NjM3M2Rk5VNtF6ySWjVFGFUfp3hHlD6Brf8kPq3gyNqaYdvPhTg=" />
</div>


    </form>
</body>
</html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .RowBGImage
    {
    background-image:url('tableBG.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    display:block;
    }
    td 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
    .HeaderPadding 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<div style="display:inline-block">
        <table id="test0_tblCell" class="RowBGImage" style="background-color:White;border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Arial;">
    <tr style="font-family:Arial Black;">
        <td class="HeaderPadding" align="left">361299</td><td class="HeaderPadding" align="right">78%</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>Type</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td> 3 Days</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span style="font:bold;font-size:xx-large;">1d 11h 30m</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .RowBGImage
    {
    background-image:url('tableBG.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    display:block;
    }
    td 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
    .HeaderPadding 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<div style="display:inline-block">
        <table id="test1_tblCell" class="RowBGImage" style="background-color:White;border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Arial;">
    <tr style="font-family:Arial Black;">
        <td class="HeaderPadding" align="left">361299</td><td class="HeaderPadding" align="right">78%</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>Type</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td> 3 Days</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span style="font:bold;font-size:xx-large;">1d 11h 30m</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .RowBGImage
    {
    background-image:url('tableBG.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    display:block;
    }
    td 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
    .HeaderPadding 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<div style="display:inline-block">
        <table id="test2_tblCell" class="RowBGImage" style="background-color:White;border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Arial;">
    <tr style="font-family:Arial Black;">
        <td class="HeaderPadding" align="left">361299</td><td class="HeaderPadding" align="right">78%</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>Type</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td> 3 Days</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span style="font:bold;font-size:xx-large;">1d 11h 30m</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .RowBGImage
    {
    background-image:url('tableBG.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    display:block;
    }
    td 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
    .HeaderPadding 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<div style="display:inline-block">
        <table id="test3_tblCell" class="RowBGImage" style="background-color:White;border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Arial;">
    <tr style="font-family:Arial Black;">
        <td class="HeaderPadding" align="left">361299</td><td class="HeaderPadding" align="right">78%</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>Type</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td> 3 Days</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span style="font:bold;font-size:xx-large;">1d 11h 30m</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .RowBGImage
    {
    background-image:url('tableBG.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    display:block;
    }
    td 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
    .HeaderPadding 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<div style="display:inline-block">
        <table id="test4_tblCell" class="RowBGImage" style="background-color:White;border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Arial;">
    <tr style="font-family:Arial Black;">
        <td class="HeaderPadding" align="left">361299</td><td class="HeaderPadding" align="right">78%</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>Type</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td> 3 Days</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span style="font:bold;font-size:xx-large;">1d 11h 30m</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .RowBGImage
    {
    background-image:url('tableBG.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    display:block;
    }
    td 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
    .HeaderPadding 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

....
......
.....
And it keeps going until 100

Comment: What is of interest is not your ASP code, but the resulting code in the browser. Could you please post that?

Comment: @HerrSerker is correct, sometimes the ASP controls render things in a silly way, for (a completely unrelated) example, creating a table for a radio button list.

Comment: By resulting code I mean HTML and CSS

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you closed your `<head>` tag.

Comment: Ok I have pasted the code above. And the head tag is closed (was a copy and paste error on my part)

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue seems to be different with different browsers and different versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style>


        .RowBGImage {
            background-image: url('tableBG.gif');
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
            background-color: White; 
            border-color: Black; 
            border-width: 1px; 
            border-style: Solid; 
            font-family: Arial;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td {
            padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
        }

        .HeaderPadding {
            padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
        }
        div.outer {
            display: block;
            width: 1000px;
        }
        div.inner {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #003366">
    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
        <div class="aspNetHidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTg2Njc2NjM3M2Rk5VNtF6ySWjVFGFUfp3hHlD6Brf8kPq3gyNqaYdvPhTg=" />
        </div>

    </form>
    <div class="outer" >
        <div class="inner">
            <table id="test0_tblCell" class="RowBGImage">
                <tr style="font-family: Arial Black;">
                    <td class="HeaderPadding" align="left">361299</td>
                    <td class="HeaderPadding" align="right">78%</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3 Days</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font: bold; font-size: xx-large;">1d 11h 30m</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="inner">
            <table id="test1_tblCell" class="RowBGImage">
                <tr style="font-family: Arial Black;">
                    <td class="HeaderPadding" align="left">361299</td>
                    <td class="HeaderPadding" align="right">78%</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3 Days</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font: bold; font-size: xx-large;">1d 11h 30m</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="inner">
            <table id="test2_tblCell" class="RowBGImage">
                <tr style="font-family: Arial Black;">
                    <td class="HeaderPadding" align="left">361299</td>
                    <td class="HeaderPadding" align="right">78%</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3 Days</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font: bold; font-size: xx-large;">1d 11h 30m</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="inner">
            <table id="test3_tblCell" class="RowBGImage">
                <tr style="font-family: Arial Black;">
                    <td class="HeaderPadding" align="left">361299</td>
                    <td class="HeaderPadding" align="right">78%</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3 Days</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font: bold; font-size: xx-large;">1d 11h 30m</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="inner">
            <table id="test4_tblCell" class="RowBGImage">
                <tr style="font-family: Arial Black;">
                    <td class="HeaderPadding" align="left">361299</td>
                    <td class="HeaderPadding" align="right">78%</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3 Days</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font: bold; font-size: xx-large;">1d 11h 30m</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

. Can you check this. If you want only 3 div then change the size of Outer DIV. I have given the fix width so that even if you decrease the size of browser it remains the same.